# Why cppreference says that copy_n can throw bad_alloc? When is it possible?

Tags: c++

I've read through `copy_n` documentation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n and there's an interesting line in `Exceptions` section:

- If the algorithm fails to allocate memory, std::bad_alloc is thrown.

What allocation is it talking about?
When we want to copy N bytes we firstly allocate a buffer ourselves with `T* buffer = new T[SIZE]` and then use `copy_n` with given `SIZE`
What situation when `copy_n` allocates memory exist?

Comment: Possibly if you `copy_n()` to an `outputIterator` that is a `back_insert_iterator` of a `vector`?

Comment: Even just assigning a copy of an element from one buffer to another may need to allocate new memory inside the element and thus can fail.

Comment: This only happens when using an `ExecutionPolicy` which is for parallel execution forms of the function; for parallel code, a safe/performant implementation might require temporary storage.

Comment: @EOF: Then there's nothing special about `std::bad_alloc`. Any algorithm can throw whatever exceptions are thrown by the iterators. So that's not it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This section is talking about the overload with a template parameter named `ExecutionPolicy`.  That overload allows the algorithm to use multiple threads to do the copying.  To facilitate that, the implementation might need to allocate some resources and that could throw.

These exceptions do not apply to the serial version of the algorithm.

Comment: isnt it the case that `*(result + i) = *(first + i)` given the "right" implementation of `operator=` can throw whatever? I dont understand why `std::bad_alloc` is mentioned explicitly and only for that particular overloads

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, the actual copy operation could throw, but that's not `copy_n` that's throwing the exception.  On the cppreference page, they are talking about the exceptions the algorithm itself could throw, and only the parallel version could fail to allocate as the serial version needs no allocation.

Comment: I just noticed the linked page even clearly states: `The overload with a template parameter named ExecutionPolicy reports errors as follows:`

Comment: makes sense, so just to reiterate, the specification only mentions exceptions thrown by the algorithm itself. Unless its declared `noexcept` you can get any exception but thats not the algorithms fault. Ie it lists only those exception that can occur even if `operator=` is `noexcept`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Correct.

Comment: @mooingduck oh, thank you. I overlooked that